# I am just trying to print the greatest number from the loop without using an array

Tags: java

*As I am trying to find the largest string's number which is input by user in which I just want to print the greatest number from the output without using an array concept*.

```
// Online Java Compiler
// Use this editor to write, compile and run your Java code online
import java.util.*;
class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String sr= sc.nextLine();
    int count = 0;
    for(int j=0;j<sr.length();j++){
        for(int k=j+1;k<sr.length();k++){
            if(sr.charAt(j)==sr.charAt(k)){
                System.out.println(k);
                break;
          }
        }
     }
   }
}
```

*my output is
2
3
5
6
*

*desired output is 6 because it is greatest out of all.*

Comment: Then don't print inside the loop. Save the greatest number in a variable and then print it after the loops.

Comment: that' what my question is.. how to save the greatest number from the variable

Comment: @SUDHANSHUSHEKHARSRIVASTAVA `count` is a variable that is never used. You could rename it `max` and instead of printing `k` when a greater value is found, you should store this value doing `max = k;`. Then, you can print the value stored into `max` after your `for` loops.

Comment: i have already done with that but if i will assign the value in max then it will iterate all the number of item and will provide the output as it is..

Answer (score 0):

As hint

```
int res = 0;
for(){
  for(){
    if(yourcondition){
      if(res < newValue) res = newValue;
    }
  }
} 

System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: what do you want to initialize inside if(yourcondition);

Comment: that should be your condition (sr.charAt(j)==sr.charAt(k)). The only thing who changed is that you dot print inside the loop. With this approach res should have the value 6 at the end of your two loops and then you can print it out

Answer (score 0):

I take an extra int variable which is "num". I use it to work the code when the digit will be > 9. Example input: "10 20 30 9".
When the index is "space" I make the value of num equal 0.

```
// Online Java Compiler
// Use this editor to write, compile and run your Java code online
import java.util.*;
class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String sr= sc.nextLine();
    int count = 0;
    int num = 0;
    for(int j=0;j<sr.length();j++){
        char ch = sr.charAt(j);
        if(ch == ' '){
            num = 0;
            continue;
        }
        num = (num * 10) + (ch - '0');
        if(num > count){
            count = num;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
   }
}
```

Comment: output is 545645650 while having input "abcabcbb".. it should be 3

Comment: can you explain why the output should be 3? Your problem isn't clear.